# Find installed package folder name using setup.py

Tags: python, setup.py

I have a package which I can install it using `setup.py`, at the end of installation process I have to copy a few dll files into my package's installation directory. How can I find my package's installation directory?
I know that this code gives me `site-packages` directory of python installation

```
from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib
print(get_python_lib())
```

but I need to find my own package's directory which is something similar to

```
C:\Program Files\Python38\Lib\site-packages\pkgname-0.0.14-py3.8-win-amd64.egg
```

As you can see the folder's name is different based on version and python version and system architecture.

Comment: can't you just import it and do pkg.__file__ or pkg.__path__ ? maybe I'm wrong

Comment: Shouldn't you add these extra binary files as package data? See for example: https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-package-data or https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#including-data-files

Comment: @DerekEden No I can not since my library needs some dll files to be in its folder to be able to import it and I want its directory to copy those files

Comment: @sinoroc Yes I actually used `data_files=[('',windows_dll_list)],` which copies a list of files to root directory of my package

Comment: I'd recommend against using `data_files` and use `package_data` instead (unless it's not possible of course). With `package_data` the extra data files are sure to be installed within the Python package alongside the Python code, no matter the environment (Python interpreter version, Python project version, etc.).

Comment: @sinoroc thanks, But the problem is that those dlls are inside another folder (vcpkg bin folder). does package_data copies them?

Comment: Instead of copying the files as part of the _install_, I would look into moving those files into the package as part of the process for the creation of the distribution (source or built), so that `package_data` can do its job.  A simple custom _distutils_/_setuptools_ command should do the job.

Comment: @sinoroc How do you mean? Can you please explain a bit more or give me some keywords to search?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203822/discussion-between-sinoroc-and-majid-hojati).